# Tomboy saves sync settings, but Ubuntu One sync is still disabled

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, tomboy

I have just installed 11.10, after erasing the previous version. On 11.04 I used to sync notes of Tomboy with my Ubuntu One account. I am trying to do the same now, but when I set the preferences on Tomboy, it redirects me on a web page for the login. I enter my username and password and all is ok on the web page. So I should just push "Save" button on Tomboy preferences to finish the process, but it is still disabled.

Some ideas about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the OP:

> Finally, I solved the problem! If it can be useful for someone...I had to change the server URL in Tomboy preferences from "https://..." to "http://...". In this way, it worked!